# Eloquent Laravel, Order comments by which one has more votes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have a post with comments, And its all working great, I even have a upvote and downvote comment function which returns the total votes (eg if it has 20 upvotes and 10 downvotes it says +10 and when you hover over it it states it has +20 upvotes and -10 downvotes)

However I want to order the comments of the post by which one has more upvotes.

I am not sure how to do this as relationships are just like so.

PostController.php:

```
public function index($category_slug, $subcategory_slug, $post_slug)
{
  return view('pages.forum-post', [
    'post' => Post::With(
    'user',
    'user.userprofile',
    'comments',
    'comments.user',
    'comments.upvotes',
    'comments.downvotes',
    'comments.user.userprofile'
    )->whereSlug($post_slug)->firstOrFail()
  ]);
}
```

Comments Model:

```
protected $appends = array('votecount');

public function upvotes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\General\Upvotes', 'commentable');
}

public function downvotes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\General\Downvotes', 'commentable');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\General\Comments', 'commentable');
}

public function getVotecountAttribute()
{
    $upVoteTotal = $this->upvotes->count();
    $DownVoteTotal = $this->downvotes->count();
    $voteTotal = $upVoteTotal - $DownVoteTotal;
    return $voteTotal;
}
```

So I ended up going with creating a new field in the comments table called total_votes and making it an int. then when the user casts a vote or down vote I increment it or decrement it -

```
Comments::find($data['comment_id'])->decrement('vote_total', 1);
```

Comment: you can create additional field inside comment model, whenever user upvotes then increase value of this field or decrease when downvotes, it allows to simple order without joins which can be slow

Comment: I don't see the problem: why not just use `orderBy('upvotes', 'DESC')`?

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to fetch the comments? It's certainly something like `$post->comments`... So order them by using the relation instead of the dynamic property: `$post->comments()->orderBy('upvotes', 'desc')->get()`

Comment: @Arcesilas its foreach ($post->comments as $c => $comment) comment code endforeach

Comment: @kmlnvm thanks I will give this a go, now to figure out the how to.. I might grab a total and submit it to the int field when a vote is cast.

Comment: `foreach ($comments = $posts->comments()->orderBy('upvotes', 'desc')->get() as $comment)`?

Comment: @kmlnvm Your answer worked, Thank you so much for that. If you made yours an answer id select it as the answer!